# Update user location to server when application is in background

Tags: android, ios, react-native, socket.io, geolocation

Mobile Technology: React native
Live Tracking using: Socket.io

I have taxi services application, in which I'm updating driver's location continuously to server. It is working fine when application is foreground. Now I want to update location of driver to server using socket on any other way when the application is in background. I need solution that works for both ios/android.

Please share your suggestions

Comment: Hi and welcome.  You should add some more detail to your question; What have you tried?  Can you show your code?

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, For background I haven't tried anything ,I know many background GPS tracking services are available ,but not getting any solution to emit socket event through background in react native

Comment: You are doing something in the foreground. The background is basically the same except you will probably need to establish the socket connection each time.

Comment: maybe user was talking about background restrictions such as dooze mode in Android Nougat and above @Paulw11

Answer (score 1):

im not sure about using socket but you can try saving your data on an sqlite database then using react-native-background-task for when your app is in the background
https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

use it like so:

```
BackgroundTask.define(() => {
  //API CALL
  BackgroundTask.finish()
})

componentDidMount() {
  BackgroundTask.schedule();
}
```

please note that it takes ATLEAST 15 minutes for it to be called on iOS

Answer (score 0):

OK, here goes not such an answer more an explanation of the situation you are in.

I've been in the same situation before and there are some things you can do to test your React Native app in the same scenario as being in 'Doze Mode'. Android introduced this as a way to limit CPU and battery usage whilst the phone is in Doze Mode. Doze mode itself is reached if the phone is stationary and/or hasn't had any interaction with the user for a set amount of time.

Firstly, with your current solution - you want to test your app in Standby/Doze Mode. You can achieve this by doing the below:

**Testing your app with Doze**

You can test Doze mode by following these steps:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze

Configure a hardware device or virtual device with an Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher system image.

- Connect the device to your development machine and install your app.
- Run your app and leave it active.
- Force the system into idle mode by running the following command:
  `$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle`
- When ready, exit idle mode by running the following command:

`$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle unforce`

- Reactivate the device by performing the following command:

`$ adb shell dumpsys battery reset`

- Observe the behavior of your app after you reactivate the device. Make sure the app recovers gracefully when the device exits Doze.

This will give you your testing scenario in order to test on Android.

**The problem:**

Android gives the apps less and less control of phones connectivity whilst in the background. It will stop networking all together and only opens in a 'Maintenance Window'. Android state:

> The Doze restriction on network access is also likely to affect your app, especially if the app relies on real-time messages such as tickles or notifications. If your app requires a persistent connection to the network to receive messages, you should use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) if possible.

The issue:

The problem is not running your app in the background, your problem will be using network in the background. For example, headless JS will run - runnable tasks will run BUT it may not be able to make any requests for network.

Possible solutions:

Using Alarms

- If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`.
- Alarms set with `setAlarmClock()`continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Putting your App into a whitelist (visit the link above for acceptable use cases).

iOS:

For React Native, I used this:

https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

This also works for Android, however the Doze mode (in my case) wouldn't send off network requests.